# AWS DynamoDB query too slow (using query, not Scan)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dynamodb-queries

It's my first time with AWS Lambdas and DynamoDB, in Python.

I have my Table with only 474 records and a total weight of 890,4 kilobytes. The filtered selection is around only 380 records.

Quite small, but still it takes severall seconds to query. Really too slow.

I use a global secondary index, as it's supposed to be the way to filter the collection.

```
dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1',
     aws_access_key_id='my_key',
     aws_secret_access_key= 'my_key')

table = dynamodb.Table('my_table_name')

response = table.query(
    IndexName='venta_arge_ok-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('venta_arge_ok').eq('True'))
```

When I test the Lambda in the console I get this figures:

- Memory Size: 128 MB
- Max Memory Used: 84

Run the test several times and got consistent times around 3 sec:

- Duration: 3270.27 ms
- Duration: 3069.37 ms
- Duration: 3290.68 ms
- Duration: 3013.34 ms
- Duration: 3157.71 ms

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try increasing the Lambda function timeout to see if it eventually succeeds? It could be timing out due to a network misconfiguration, if you deployed the Lambda function in a VPC.

Comment: @MarkB just updated the info, after increasing the timeouot. The query is just above 3 sec, but it seems still too much for such a small data collection. Or maybe it's normal and I'm confused?

Comment: Is Lambda function in the same AWS region as the DynamoDB table? `us-east-1`?

Comment: Typically no need for access key and secret key in a Lambda function. Assign the appropriate permissions to the IAM role you configure the Lambda function with.

Comment: What are you timing here? The actual DDB query execution, the Lambda start to end time, the client time from API request to API response received? If Lambda start/end, did you log timings for just the query?

Comment: Try increasing the function size as well. 128MB is so small. Take note that increasing memory size also increases CPU and network.

Comment: The Lambda function is in the same region. Access keys was only included here cause I copied from my CLI tests (not in actual function. The timming is for the whole Lamda execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Noel Llevares pointed, the issue was related with memory size (and it's related CPU power increase).

The same Lambda gave the following results for each memmory size tested:

128 MB - 3 sec
256 MB - 1.5 sec
512 MB - 0.75 sec
1024 MB - 0.4 sec